# Can't select and hide any previous element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm about lose my mind with this problem. No form of jQuery selector seems to work in dynamically finding any elements above the link.  I'm trying to access an element above the link and hide it. Using things like `parent()`, `prev()`, `before()`, `closest()`, ect. will show a non-null object but it won't respond to the `hide()` method.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div id="test_fields">
            <li id="test_input" class="string input optional stringish">
                 <label class="label" for="test_input">Ingredient name</label>
                 <input type="text" name="test_input" value="afsfasf" id="test_input">
             </li>
       </div>
       <input type="hidden" id="recipe_recipe_ingredients_attributes_0__destroy" name="recipe[recipe_ingredients_attributes][0][_destroy]">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="test_link" css_class="small" onclick="javascript:remove_fields(this)">Remove Ingredient</a>
        </div>
   </div>

function remove_fields(link) 
{
   $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val('1'); // this doesn't work

    var divToHide = $(link).prev('div');

    $(divToHide).hide() // this doesn't work
    //$('#test_fields').hide(); //this works
}
```

Comment: Are you open to other way of achieving the same goal? Your HTML structure is not ideal for doing something like this

Comment: I know you meant "shape or form" metaphorically but this is javascript, and shape and form mean very different things.  Beware of flippant question titles!

Comment: Your var is `div_to_hide`, but in the next line, you spell it like `divToHide`.

Comment: Use simple yet descriptive variables in your demo, my head is spinning from all of the underscores and lengthy names.

Answer (score 0):

you can try **.closest()** and **.find()**

```
function remove_fields(link) {
   $(link).closest('div[class^="col-xs"]').find("input[type=hidden]").val('1'); 

    var div_to_hide = $(link).closest('div[class^="col-xs"]').find('#test_fields');

    $(div_to_hide).hide();
    //$('#test_fields').hide(); //this works
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the link as below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="test_link" css_class="small" onclick="javascript:remove_fields($(this))">Remove Ingredient</a>
```

I'm not sure. But maybe this is the problem. Because I remember that I have had problem with 'this'previously and when I replaced that, it performed the job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately, this didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't change hidden input's "value" attribute by using `.val()`. You need to use:

```
$(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").attr('value', '1');
```

As I'm not really sure what do you want to do with this input, I'll just let it go like this.

`.prev()` fn goes only **one** previous element in the structure. As `input` is a `<a>`'s previous element, you can't select `div` like that. You can use `.siblings()` for instance.

```
$(link).siblings('div').hide();
```

Comment: Sorry - the "divToHide" was a typo.    Not the problem here.   When it's corrected, it doesn't change the problem.    Also, assigning the hidden value to 1 is exactly what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you break the code in pieces, it gets easier.

First I took the 'Link', from it I grabbed the nearest div above it, then I picked up the input.

I did not make many changes to your code.

```js
function remove_fields(link) 
{
    var $link =$(link);

    var $divToHide = $link.closest('div');
  
    $divToHide.find("input[type='hidden']").val('1');

    $divToHide.hide()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div id="test_fields">
            <li id="test_input" class="string input optional stringish">
                 <label class="label" for="test_input">Ingredient name</label>
                 <input type="text" name="test_input" value="afsfasf" id="test_input">
             </li>
       </div>
       <input type="hidden" id="recipe_recipe_ingredients_attributes_0__destroy" name="recipe[recipe_ingredients_attributes][0][_destroy]">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="test_link" css_class="small" onclick="javascript:remove_fields(this)">Remove Ingredient</a>
        </div>
   </div>
```